# Using Angular 16 to Post thousands of records to Rest API using an Observable. Gives errors after a few hundred posts

Tags: angular, http, post

Looping thru a collection for each member and calling service to post member to  rest api.   After several hundred posts immediately get many failures and it keeps processing some even though thousands instantly get a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Is observable not the right choice here?  And is making synchronous a good idea, even though it will make things much slower ?

Thank in advance

I have tried to use the observable to pos thousands of records in a collection to WEB API.
I have tried to async await.
I will try to do concatMap, though I'm not sure if it would be appropriate since each post is not dependent on any previous posts.
I will try to try to post in batches of 500 records.  500 records seems to work well without errors

Comment: have you considered that could be a web server problem? Have you tried to do a stress test on the web server to see if it can handle to many requests?

Comment: i know it is not the best solution but you could use the `retry` operator of RxJS this would resubscribe on error

Comment: Oscar Ludick :  The same server using the same API's perform with a different client implementation.    I also use the retry operator , and I set to 3.     I believe the issue is the observable itself, and it just makes thousands of calls before any calls are complete, and it's not modulating itself.      I need to modulate it manually I believe.   Will keep trying.  Thanks for your comments.